# SDCC generates unnecessary division by zero

Tags: c, compilation, divide-by-zero, sdcc, stm8

I'm using SDCC to compile for a STM8 microcontroller. Compiling the following file results in a seemingly unnecessary `div` instruction - which is very slow on the STM8.

```
char a[1];
char b;

void foo() __interrupt(1) {
    char c = a[0];
    b = c >> 0;
}

void main() {
}
```

Compiling with `sdcc -mstm8 file.c` results in the following assembly:

```
_foo:
    clr a
    div x, a
    ld  a, _a+0
    ld  _b+0, a
    iret
```

The function seems to work as expected, however I can't see why the first two instructions are required.

Comment: did you compile with optimization on? And please show a [mcve]. A broken if block isn't meaningful

Comment: The [manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/cd00161709-stm8-cpu-programming-manual-stmicroelectronics.pdf) says that if the denominator is zero, the operand registers are unaffected. And the `div` is interruptible. So it's a zero being pushed, not a remainder.  In all this looks like an intentional delay.  I wonder if it's something to do with interrupt protocol. Maybe it's time for a data register to latch or something.

Comment: And what is your question that **we** can answer? -- BTW, the SDCC project has a friendly user mailing list. You might like to ask there for the reasons.

Comment: Where is the `iret` instruction? This doesn't look like correct/complete disassembly of an ISR. Does it make any difference if you drop obsolete C style and write the function correctly as `void updateDisplay(void) __interrupt(23)`?

Comment: @phuclv I've rewritten the question with the minimal amount of code possible to see the div instruction. My SDCC version is 4.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that's a bug somewhere in the compiler because if `b = c >> 0` is changed to `b = c << 0`, `b = c + 0`, `b = a[0]`... then no such thing happens. The behavior is observed on both optimized and unoptimized code. But if you optimize for size (`--opt-code-size`) then only the `div` is there, the `clr` instruction isn't emitted. You might want to [report that to the developers](https://sourceforge.net/p/sdcc/_list/tickets)

[Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMALOXUYBVAM7YACgA8QAcgAMM8gCse5dq3qgA%2BjtTkxnVEQINq2epgDC6dgFcAtvRAAmcucwAZAvWwA5BwBG2KQgAOzkAA7oIsQm9NZ2ji6R0bEMXj7%2B9kEh4QbYRnFMRKykRAkOTq75hQzFpUQZfoHBYfolZRVJ1R2N3s3ZraEAlProtqSoXDKoSKUA1KwApACsAELcqwAiSwDMa0tyAIKzCwF7B8eHRwBu6ASY83ToEMPzOt5EwaS2EUQQ3DeS1ClyO83B81OpEh8z2W0WqzWcm2F2uEPmAVhu3hqCxuD2uHmyP212BOyuxzuD3m9lY3lesJBpNC5KOMlG7FkK0UTnkinQsks8xE40m2Fhzl23EURFkCmGowA1iAVnI1LJeIp7Cq1byFOQBTJFCIQGrZXzRnBYCgMDh8MQyJRqIJmGxODx%2BC7RBJpHzlMl1JoQDotHoasZTBB3F0nHw3BYmlkciAAJwpGIR%2BI2Soe9NpeiJlohNPhoq9GO50t1XqFwbF9oNCtxkQ1/pJ1op0YiiZTWRQhHrTYrHYk47986jo7XKmPZ4Mj6Mb6/f6Axmg9H93FwgdIlGT9GY7db3aWPZC4mgsmkyn3R60%2BlAplXFnXdnqmTc8h6/mC4WiqYSrszgynK7KjEg2CsDgISvO%2BmrkNqqpfqBBqyMaprkOa8pKjq767DyKGGiBFrkFaCDwBANroPYEQEJwFBUBAGA0XRrQiJgqCoLw3BqjQdFfKQJoQAEKEBN4pQAJ6yNK5DMfY5hEAA8vQ7BSX6OC0po7rqQQpAFMYNzYCafrYJIBS2F80mKJ82Ccn67AEAEpCSdYOAoUQpAENqMjSqMLosBwXBxl6YhSChKjcGoGjaLoaiOSakCjOgfxxMZAC09gtvYAAc8xpWlyVEGltrYGlIgRNg2CYMatn6XEZgWE28aeG2RaqFEGZxE1HX5rWyaRVW9D1J02ZJANtW1ENraZG1A3lqNsYNmUfWtICYw9kFHJcgRfqGkwWyWEKvAAHTcMdcjzBA9okNCSySpF8zWCx9GAauljEdh5AQVBrSwcqSF2fBiG6oRaH6BhWFvmRlFoNRtH0U6TFw6xITsZx3G8fxwRCSJfpifQklWbJ1HyYwymqShGnRdp%2BqEHphSGcZ%2BqmeZlk%2BdZi52fqDlOS5WDTPqHleVZfkMK6gW5iFPrhQG0XBrFPMJbBhWpbIGVZdlNWGJmDVWAtqjuCtISRT1mbdakmZG6og3DeU%2BvjdrZYNFbc2NvbS19DNdY8F2/5cM4W0fjt%2Bp7QdR2nedl3XWQgGuI9yMvXdQFvO9mGgQqX2QdB1CB0DuHfqhRrg2a6c4QDsj4chu1g5DGd2cBVchzXpfkIZgn1bwQA%3D%3D)

Comment: I reported and it was fixed less than an hour later: https://sourceforge.net/p/sdcc/bugs/3233/